# android studio button not working

Tags: java, android

I created a android studio button for my app and when I click on the register button it doesn't work . I don't get any errors it just doesn't work . When the user clicks the register button I want to go to the login activity .

RegisterActivity.java :

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest( username, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}

}
```

activity_register.xml :

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/bRegister"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPassword"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="OnClickListener" />
```

RegisterRequest :

```
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

 private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://app.comxa.com/register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

 public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is not a question. What have you tried to do to debug the problem? Add some logging statements somewhere so you know what your code is doing.

Comment: but that's what's happening

Comment: when I click the button . It doesn't work

Comment: Your code seems to demonstrate that the onClickListener is set on the button, so maybe your Volley call is not working.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it .

Comment: Well, you probably should show a [mcve] with an [edit] to the question. In particular, `RegisterRequest` is missing from the code you've shown. Additionally, a `public void OnClickListener(View v)` method is missing from this class, so you should be getting an error in the Logcat.

Comment: registerrequest is at the bottom on my registeractivity code

Comment: I'm not getting an error

Comment: Your usage of the class is at the bottom of the code in the question, but you need to actually [edit] your question to show us the `RegisterRequest` class itself.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just did

Comment: If I go to that URL in that class with a GET or POST request, there is not JSON being sent back, so maybe that is why "*it doesn't work*"

Comment: my app name isn't "app" . But when i click on the url it works . it send me to the index

Answer (score 1):

in xml, attribute `android:onClick` must content the name of your method instead of listener name, for instance:

```
android:onClick="mybutton"
```

and in class:

```
public void mybutton(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.mybutton){
        //handle the click here and make whatever you want
  }
}
```

The other way to do that is using onClickListener as follows:

in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
```

and in class:

```
Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: remove  android:onClick attribute in xml and test it,

Comment: try declaring button as global var or checking if libraries for onclick are right sometimes it's the main problem

Comment: try showing only a toast to test, it possible there are warnings not showed

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to do this:

1. Register onClickListener for your button and without onClick attribute in xml.
2. create method with input(View view) in java class and call the method name in your xml onClick attribute. In this way you dont need to register any listener for buttons.

Comment: when I tried doing it without the onclick attribute it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your button looks like it should work, but for clarity, you can check this

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("HELLO", "Register Button Clicked");
```

Now, for reasons that "it doesn't work", you should check your Volley code. In particular, verify that the third parameter of `RegisterRequest` (the callback) is actually being used and executed.

You can verify that the callback is called with

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d("HELLO", response);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

All you need to do is look at the logcat for those messages.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices to do this:

Register `onClickListener` for your button and without `onClick` attribute in xml.
create method with `input(View view)` in Java class and call the method name in your xml `onClick` attribute. In this way you don't need to register any listener for buttons.